# Add UILabel Mask to UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, mask, uivisualeffectview

I have an `UIImageView`, `UIVisualEffectView`, and an `UILabel` on my `ViewController`. The `UIVisualEffectView` blurs the `UIImageView` behind it. I would like to mask the `UIVisualEffectView` with the text of the `UILabel`. Like this image:

[image]

How would I do this? I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your `UILabel` as maskView of your `UIVisualEfectView` and the trick is that you need add a container for your `UIVisualEfectView` and your `UILabel` and set the background color for this container view as `UIColor.clear`

```
self.visualEfectView.mask = self.label
self.visualEfectView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**View Hierarchy Setup**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!